# Is the analog clock widget somehow tied into the unlock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, malware, lock-screen-widgets

I've encountered something bizarre on my phone which I think is just an innocent side effect, but I wanted to make sure that it wasn't indicative of something malicious.

From time to time, right after I unlock the phone, the LastPass prompt pops up and asks me if I want to input my master password in order for it to autofill the password for "Clock Widget."  I don't use the clock widget on the lock screen, though.

I don't ever provide it the password, but initially I was concerned that there might be a program masking itself as the clock widget.  Since the prompt is so closely correlated with the unlocking, I have to believe, though, that LastPass is offering to fill in my unlock code, even though it can't.

Is the clock widget somehow associated with the part of the OS that controls the unlocking of the device?  Is there any legitimate reason why it would ask for a password?

I have an LG G2 running 4.4.2 and I have scanned the device with Malwarebytes Anti-Malware as well as Kaspersky and I haven't found anything at all with either.

I wasn't able to grab a screenshot before the LastPass prompt disappeared, unfortunately.

Comment: What's this LastPass you're talking about?

Comment: @MANI See https://lastpass.com/  It's a well-known app and browser add-in

Comment: Looks like pretty famous and secure too. Then why bother about giving password when prompted. If still unsure try to grab a screenshot when it happens again.

Comment: @MANI I trust LastPass, I'm just curious about why the clock widget would prompt for a password.